# Items are duplicated when displayed in a view

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

The code below creates a dialog window with two views: `QListView` on a left, `QTableView` on a right. Both views share the same `DataModel` instance. The left view displays the same name of the animal three times. How to tweak the code so the left view lists no duplicated animals.

[image]

```
import os,sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

elements={'Animals':{1:'Bison',2:'Panther',3:'Elephant'},'Birds':{1:'Duck',2:'Hawk',3:'Pigeon'},'Fish':{1:'Shark',2:'Salmon',3:'Piranha'}}


class ListModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)   
        self.items=[]    
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)   

    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 4

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)): return QtCore.QVariant()
        key=str(self.items[index.row()])
        column=index.column()

        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if not column: return key
            else: return elements.get(key,{}).get(column)  

    def buildItems(self):
        for species in elements:
            for number in elements[species]:
                number=self.rowCount()
                self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), number+1, 0)                
                self.items.append(species)
                self.endInsertRows()


class TableModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def headerData(self, column, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role==QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            if orientation==QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return QtCore.QVariant(int(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter))
            return QtCore.QVariant(int(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter))
        if role!=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if orientation==QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            return QtCore.QVariant("Species %s"%column)

        return QtCore.QVariant(int(column+1))

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        mainLayout=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)   

        self.listModel=ListModel()
        self.listModel.buildItems() 

        self.tableModel=TableModel()
        self.tableModel.setFilterKeyColumn(0)    
        self.tableModel.setSourceModel(self.listModel)

        self.viewA=QtGui.QListView()
        self.viewA.setModel(self.listModel)
        self.viewA.clicked.connect(self.onClick) 

        self.viewB=QtGui.QTableView()         
        self.viewB.setModel(self.tableModel)

        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewA)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.viewB)    
        self.show()

    def onClick(self):
        index=self.viewA.currentIndex()
        key=self.listModel.data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)  
        value=self.listModel.data(index, QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole)        
        self.tableModel.setFilterRegExp('%s'%key)

window=Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I think that problem is in this row which is not needed there for number in elements[species]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you don't want to add every `species` `number` of times. So remove this row:

```
for number in elements[species]:
```

Also you reassing value to this variable at the next line.

Comment: Please post working code example to illustrate your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the `for` loops of your `buildItems` function when you insert the items, try to check this.